# If $EF$ meets $AD$ at $Y$ prove that $\frac{AY}{YD} = \frac{\lambda}{(\lambda+1)}$.

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles

> $ABCD$ is a trapezium with $AD \parallel BC$, $X$ lies on $AD$ such that $\frac{AX}{XD} = \lambda$. The straight lines $AB$ and $CD$ meet at $E$, and the lines $BX$ and $AC$ meet at $F$. If $EF$ meets $AD$ at $Y$ prove that $\frac{AY}{YD} = \frac{\lambda}{(\lambda+1)}$.

**What I Tried**: Here is a Picture :-

[image]

Let $BX$ meet $CE$ at $G$.

I was able to apply Menelaus Theorem on $5$ triangles and got $5$ equations. These are :-

\begin{align}
\frac{DG}{GE} * \frac{EB}{AB} * \frac{AX}{DX} = 1.  && \text{} \tag 1\\ 
\\
\frac{DX}{AX} * \frac{AF}{FC} * \frac{CG}{DG} = 1. && \text{} \tag 2\\
\\
\frac{XY}{AY} * \frac{AE}{BE} * \frac{BF}{FX} = 1. && \text{} \tag 3\\
\\
\frac{DG}{GE} * \frac{EF}{YF} * \frac{YX}{DX} = 1. && \text{} \tag 4\\
\\
\frac{DY}{AY} * \frac{AF}{FC} * \frac{CE}{DE} = 1. && \text{} \tag 5\\
\end{align}

I can notice there are some common ratios in some of these lines, but after these I am not able to get anything useful after here. I know I need to reach $\frac{AY}{YD}$ (in Eqn. $(5)$) from $\frac{AX}{XD}$ (in Eqn. $(2)$), but I do not know how.

Can someone help me? Thank You.

**Edit**:- I wrote some equations wrong, I have corrected them now.

Comment: This doesn't look right. By rearranging and simplifying your last equation, we get $\frac{AY}{YD}=\frac{AE}{DE}$. But the ratio on the right-hand side should be constant, while the one on the left-hand side depends on $\lambda$.

Comment: @EvangelosBampas ohh, if you are right, then did I make a mistake on writing some of  these $5$ equations? I had checked them before but I did not find any.

Comment: Yes, probably. You may want to recheck all 5.

Comment: Ok I found $1$ mistake in the $1$st equation. It should be $\frac{AX}{DX}$ instead of $\frac{BX}{GX}$. The figures always confuse me. Can you please recheck and tell if that helps or not?

Comment: Well, there must be something wrong with the 5th equation as well. Please recheck **all** 5 equations, and edit the question accordingly.

Comment: @EvangelosBampas Checked. I found $2$ more mistakes, confused myself by considering point $F$ to be $E$. I am hoping the equations are correct now.

Comment: Can someone try this problem now? I seem to stuck like the same way before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $H$ be the point where $EF$ meets $BC$. Then, by similar triangles:

$$
{AY\over DY}={BH\over CH}={XY\over AY}={AX-AY\over AD-DY},
$$
whence:
$$
{AY\over DY}={AX\over AD}={AX\over AX+XD}={\lambda\over\lambda+1}.
$$

Comment: Why the downvotes?

Comment: I didn't downvote, but it's in poor taste to call things "obvious" when you're trying to help someone with a question.

Comment: Uh, OK then: I'll remove the obvious. Didn't intend to hurt the feelings of people out there.

Comment: @Intelligentipauca I didn't downvote either, I think this is a good answer, probably more simple than what I was thinking of. Thank you for this.